# Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, foreach, stack, unhandled-exception

I am trying to print the contents of a Stack.

[Stack Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.8)

When I make the attempt I get the following error.

> Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which is happening on the **foreach** line of my code.  I'm unsure why this is happening since I thought I was using the example given on the page I linked.  Example would be...

```
        foreach( string number in numbers )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
```

Following is my code.  Everything appears to be functional except this part which throws the error.

```
            foreach(var s in stack)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
```

...and this is my code.

```
using System;

namespace Exercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var stack = new Stack();
            stack.Push(1);
            stack.Push(2);
            stack.Push(3);

            foreach(var s in stack)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Exercise
{
    internal class Stack : IEnumerable
    {
        private object _object;
        private List<object> list = new List<object>();
        private IEnumerator Enumerator;
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => Enumerator;

        internal object Pop()
        {
            if (list.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use .Pop() if list count equals 0.");

            _object = list.FirstOrDefault();

            list.RemoveAt(0);

            return _object;
        }

        internal void Push(object obj)
        {
            _object = obj;

            if (_object == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use .Push() if object is null.");

            list.Insert(0, _object);
        }

        internal void Clear()
        {
            if (list.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use .Clear() if list is empty.");

            list.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this to print the contents of the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GetEnumerator` method returns null because the field `Enumerator` was never explicitly initialized, so it got the default value null.

Then, the foreach loop calls `.GetEnumerator()`, receives a null and tries to access the `.Current` property of null, so you get a `NullReferenceExcpetion`.

To fix this, you can use the following implementation:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    while (list.Any())
        yield return Pop();
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but it doesn't Enumerate the entire collection because you're increasing `i` as `list.Count` decreases. In this example, when `list.Count` is 1, `i` is 2, and the `for` loop ends. Instead, use `while (list.Any())`.

Comment: Thank you Gur Galler for that.  That was what I was missing.  Also, thank you @rfmodulator for mentioning the fix to Gur Galler code.  Everything works now.